# dpkg problem lock file

Tags: permissions, dpkg, input, output

While installing a package I have got a dpkg error. When I try to:

```
       sudo dpkg --configure -a: 
       dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
       sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
       cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Read-only file system     
       sudo chmod +w /var/lib/dpkg/lock
       chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Read-only file system
```

The problem is that anytime I try to use a fsck, ps, gedit I get:

```
       -bash: /usr/bin/ps: Input/output error
```

I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04. pls save me from the evil

Comment: Please use the `mount` command to verify that your root file system is mounted read-only. If so, try to remount it read-write.

Comment: It’s most likely certainly not a `dpkg` lock file issue … The issue appears to be that your root filesystem is mounted read-only which prevents your applications from doing their required file-writing operations … Remounting your root filesystem read and write should resolve that.